# Create conditional object dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create an object based on the contents of another object. I have an object that contains the following key/values:

```
var inputObject = {
    "color": [
        "black",
        "red",
        "green"
    ],
    "bottom": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
    ],
    "top": [
        "L",
        "M"
    ]
    }
```

I would like to modify this object so that it creates a dynamic number of keys. Here is my intended output:

```
var outputObject = {

    "blackBottom": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
    ],
    "redBottom": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
    ],
    "greenBottom": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
    ],
    "blackTop": [
        "L",
        "M"
    ],
    "redTop": [
        "L",
        "M"
    ],
    "greenTop": [
        "L",
        "M"
    ]
}
```

Where the following conditions are met:

- Should there be no colors inside the `"color"` key, or the `"color"` key not exist, then create all 4 `"color" + "Bottom" and "Top"`
- Should there be only one color inside the `"color"` object, then only create that `"color" + "Bottom" and "Top"`
- Should there be only no entries in `"Bottom"`, then only create the `"color" + "Bottom"`

How do I create the `outputObject`?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your problem. Just a reminder, people here really don't like doing your homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over each color and fill resulting object using `reduce`

```js
// The ES6 version, with the flexibility requested

const generate = ({color: colors, bottom, top}) => 
   colors.reduce(
     (acc, color) => Object.assign(acc, 
       bottom && {[`${color}Bottom`]: [...bottom]},
       top && {[`${color}Top`]: [...top]}
       ), 
     {})

// The ES5 version

function generateOldGoodES5(input) {
   // extract values from input w/o destructuring
   var colors = input.color,
       bottom = input.bottom,
       top = input.top;

   return colors.reduce(function(out, color){
     // assign corresponding properties
     out[color + 'Bottom'] = bottom.slice(); // copy array
     out[color + 'Top'] = top.slice(); // copy array

     return out
   }, {});

}

var inputObject = {
    "color": [
        "black",
        "red",
        "green"
    ],
    "bottom": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
    ],
    "top": [
        "L",
        "M"
    ]
    }
    
console.log("ES6 Output")
console.log(generate(inputObject))

console.log("ES5 Output")
console.log(generateOldGoodES5(inputObject))
```

Comment: Nice use of ES6! However, i dont think the OP will understand without an explanation...

Comment: @Jonasw ES5 version added with some comments.

Comment: I like the ES6 version, however it only works when all `"color"`, `"top"`, and `"bottom"` exist. Is there any way that the solution works when either `"top"` or `"bottom"` do not exist?

Comment: @black_sheep07 in the func parameters, you can use bottom = [], top = [] to make it work.

Comment: @black_sheep07 You could do it like this `Object.assign(acc, top && {[`${color}`Top]: [...top]}, bottom &&/*same here*/}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add informations dynamically to your `outputObject` dynamically just like this:

```
var outputObject = {
   // unconditional things
   exampleUnconditional: [
      "someValue"
   ]
};

if(inputObject. /* your condition here */) {
    outputObject.exampleConditional = [
        "someContent"
    ] 
};
```

And so as result, `outputObject` will be like:

```
{
    exampleUnconditional: [
       "someValue"
    ],
    exampleConditional: [
        "someContent"
    ]
}
```